# Image size not work properly in figure's environment

Tags: floats, includegraphics

I'm new to Latex. I want to create a command to automatic trim the image and put it in a figure's environment with caption but the result show like this :
[image]

I want the image's width = text's width, but the image is way too big so the caption go inside it and there's one text line is missing behind the image under the equation (8) too. I did some research but nothing work. How to fix this please? Here is my code:

```
\newcommand{\includetrimgraphics}[4][]{
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    %\scalebox{1}[1]{\includegraphics[trim=0 50 0 50,#1]{#2}}
    %\resizebox{\totalheight}{!}{\includegraphics[trim=0 50 0 50,#1]{#2}}
    \includegraphics[trim=0 50 0 50,#1]{#2}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{#4}
\end{figure}}
```

And here is how I call the command:

```
\includetrimgraphics[width=\textwidth]{images.png}{Normaliser le ratio entre $\Delta z1_{max}$ et $\Delta z2_{max}$}{fig:1}
```

Comment: You should probably also add the `clip` option.

Comment: BTW you'll probably get burned at some point because of your use of the `H` placement. It is _not_ recommended, learn to use proper floats

Comment: @daleif I tried the `clip` option but the image is then cropped.

Comment: I think the problem is caused by `trim=0 50 0 50`. Remove that or change it. I would suggest something, but I don't know why you have that there in the first place, and what you were trying to achieve with it. If you don't want to crop the image, what are you trying to "trim"?

Comment: @frabjous I'm trying to "trim" the blank space in the image, if I use "clip" it will crop too much. But like what you suggested, the problem caused exactly by the "trim" option so I just remove it, everything works now, thank you very much ^_^

Comment: It doesn't look like there is much blank space on the top and bottom of the image (which is all that was "trimming").

Comment: @frabijous yeah but can you explain why the "trim" is not working here please ?

Comment: trim is working and produces exactly the effect that you show, it makes latex leave less space, so the following text over-prints. What did you expect it to do if not that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it should crop the image, not the figure box I think? this is what I read from the manual:
Gives parts of the graphic to not show. Takes four arguments, separated by spaces, that are given in TeX dimensions, as with \includegraphics[.., trim= 0in 0.1in 0.2in 0.3in, ...]{...}. These give the amounts of the graphic not to show, that is, LaTeX will crop the picture by 0 inches on the left, 0.1 inches on the bottom, 0.2 inches on the right, and 0.3 inches on the top.

Comment: No (it is my code, I know what it does:-) it changes the space left for the image, the parts ouside that space will will show unless you also use `clip`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ahhhhhhh now I understand why it displayed like that when I put in the "trim" option. Thanks for the explanation ^_^